# How do I create a keyboard accessory view with Auto Layout in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, inputaccessoryview

I want to add a "Done" button and a segmented control to a Decimal Pad keyboard. Ideally I would like to lay out a keyboard accessory view with Auto Layout in Interface Builder.

Is this even possible? Do I create a new XIB or can I do it in the existing Storyboard scene somehow? How do I attach the accessory view to the appropriate text field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would you mind doing it programmatically?

Typically you take a UIToolbar to a UITextField with your items, but you may need to subview the UISegmentedControl;

```
UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:...
// Customize segmentedControl's properties here.

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

[keyboardToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];
[keyboardToolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
[textField setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
```

EDIT: It is possible to create the toolbar initially in IB, but you have to drag it off the view and to the left hand sidebar containing the scene and link it to a reference outlet, then assign it with `setInputAccessoryView` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Is it only *ever* done with a UIToolBar? Is that what I'm missing? Nothing anywhere I've found in the docs implies this is the case. I would like to do it in IB if at all possible, hence the phrasing of the question.

Comment: It may not be the only way, as you're able to assign any UIView to it. The problem I've had though, is that the frame of the accessory view seems to be fixed to the shape of a UINavigationBar/UIToolbar as to why I had suggested UIToolbar when I had tried this, but I may have to do it again later to test it out. As for IB, I myself haven't found it, but thought this solution may still seem of some use.

Comment: so easy... i wish i could give you another +1