# Swift: Programmatically add UIButton above keyboard

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to add a (custom with a corner radius of 25.0) UIButton to hover just above the keyboard in my view controller.

I have tried accomplishing this on my own by adding this button to a toolbar with the following code, however, I am not looking for a toolbar:

```
    let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    loginButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    loginButton.titleLabel?.text = "Sign Up"
    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signUp), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: loginButton)
    toolbar.items = [customButton]
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    //...
    //When credentials are valid, show/enable button...
    usernameEmailField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

**How can I add a UIButton to hover just above the keyboard at all times?**

Thank you.

Comment: You should learn about how add keyboard accesories. Following link may be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573045/how-do-i-create-a-keyboard-accessory-view-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. Please try this

```
//create toolbar object
        let doneToolBar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 44))
        doneToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
        //add barbuttonitems to toolbar
        let flexsibleSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil) // flexible space to add left end side
        let doneButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: #selector(UITextField.didPressDoneButton))
        doneToolBar.items = [flexsibleSpace,doneButton]
        //assing toolbar as inputAccessoryView
        textField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolBar
        doneToolBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Thanks but this is pretty much what I already have just with spacing on the left. Do you know how I can add a custom UIButton, not UIBarButtonItem, to the toolbar? My current approach puts the custom UIButton in the toolbar but removes the cornerRadius and isn't sized properly:     
`let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: loginButton)` `toolbar.items = [customButton]`